# Laravel get request pass input data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass some input data from a get request to a view in my controller. I was wondering if this is possible or am I doing it incorrectly? The data I want to pass is from a text field within a form as below:

```
    <form id='query_form' role='form' action='{{ URL::route('getUserbase'); }}' method="get">

                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='input-group'>   
                        <input type='text' id='query-bar' required class='form-control' placeholder='Enter search query..' name='entered_query' />                    
                        <span class='input-group-btn'>
                            <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-color' value='Go' />
                        </span>      
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
```

I am submitting it with ajax:

```
function standardGet($action)
{
    $.get($action, function(data, status)
    {
        $("body").html(data);
    });   
}

   $('#query_form').submit(function(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       var action   =   $(this).attr('action');
       standardGet(action);
   });
```

In my laravel controller:

```
public function getUserBase()
{
    if(Request::ajax())
        return View::make('admin.plugins.userbase')->with('search_request', Request::get('entered_query'));

    else
     return View::make('admin.plugins.userbase');
}
```

With this code Request::get('entered_query') is null, I've also tried Input::get('entered_query'). Any ideas?

EDIT: Route for getUserbase():

```
Route::get('/admin/panel/userbase', array('uses' => 'AdminController@getUserbase', 'as' => 'getUserbase'));
```

EDIT2:
Also to clarify if i replace the value in with any value I can access it, I just can't access the input from the form: return View::make('admin.plugins.userbase')->with('search_request', "test");

Comment: Can you add `getUserBase()` route in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing any data to your method. Try

```
$('#query_form').submit(function(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       var action   =   $(this).attr('action');
       var method   = 'GET';
       $.ajax({
          type: method,
          url:action,
          data: $('#query_form').serialize(),
          success: function() {

          }
       })
   });
```

In your `getUserbase` method

```
dd(Input::all());
```

**Edited::**

Pass what you wanted variable to your view like the following

```
return View::make('admin.plugins.userbase', compact('search_request', Input::get('entered_query'));
```

Check what you had passed variable is not Null in your view like the following

```
@if(isset($search_request))
  {{ $search_request }} //is not NULL echo it
@endif
```

Comment: Getting error 500: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can I see errors in screenshot or more details? @joe

Comment: I think I am trying to access the variable incorrectly, previously when using ->with() with View::make() I was able to access the variables by just referencing it like so: $entered_query and could check it by isset(entered_query). If I pass dd(Input::all()) i can see the string: array(2) { ["entered_query"]=> string(17) "username=test123" ["builder-filter"]=> string(0) "" } but how can I access it in my result?

Comment: So, you can pass like `return View::make('admin.plugins.userbase')->with('search_request', Input::get('entered_query'));` @joe

Comment: just checked by passing dd(Input::get('entered_query')) and i can see the string it but I cannot check it in my result by doing: if(isset($search_request)) Am I able to see the variable by just referencing $search_request (I was able to do this before when using with())

Comment: Side-note: Blade-shorthand for 
`@if(isset($search_request))
  {{ $search_request }} //is not NULL echo it
@endif`

Would be `{{ $search_request or '' }}`

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not sent at backend:

```
function standardGet($action)
{
    $.get($action, {data : data}, function(data, status){ // send data here.
        $("body").html(data);
    });   
}

   $('#query_form').submit(function(event)
   {
       event.preventDefault();
       var action   =   $(this).attr('action');
       var data = $(this).serialize(); // serialize this form.
       standardGet(action, data); // pass it here
   });
```

and i think you have to change this:

```
Request::get('entered_query')
```

to this:

```
Request::get('name') // it should give you "entered_query"
Request::get('value') // it should give you typed text of input[name="entered_query"]
```

or as i see at the documentation they have used `Input::get()` so you can try with these:

```
Input::get('name') // it should give you "entered_query"
Input::get('value') // it should give you typed text of input[name="entered_query"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
    $('#query_form').submit(function(event)
       {
           event.preventDefault();
           var action   =   $('#formid').serialize(); //formid or formclass
           standardGet(action);
       });

Request::get('entered_query'); or 
Input::get('entered_query');
```